# Convert string into term

Tags: python

I'm looking for an easy way to convert a String `s`, e.g. `s = "x+1.0"`, into a term I can use as a mathematical term. The goal is to find the y-values for some x-values in a specific space.

So for `s = "x+1.0"` I would get `6` for `x=5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` to do so:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> s = "x+1.0"
>>> eval(s)
6.0
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are just trying to convert a string into a Python expression and evaluate it.

You can do this with `eval`, with all the [usual warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/391161).

```
x = 5
s = eval("x+1.0") # Now s = 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `eval` keyword: it allows the string to be evaluated as an expression.

```
x = 2
s = "x+1.0"
k = eval(s)
print k
```

Output: 3.0